# Laravel PHP: Request's and $this-> in static functions

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a controller called ProductController. In that controller I have added pagination but I repeat the same code in each of my other controllers. Which is a no-no. I cannot figure out how to move the code below to its own static helper function mainly because of the Request object and the $this->validate function. I am an old procedural programmer and I am still getting my head wrapped around Laravel. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
class ProductController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
     {

        // Pagination. Grab sort_by, direction and page size.  If empty assign defaults
        $sort_by = (empty($request->input('sort_by'))) ? 'id' : $request->input('sort_by');
        $direction = (empty($request->input('direction'))) ? 'asc' : $request->input('direction');
        $page_size = (empty($request->input('page_size'))) ? '10' : $request->input('page_size');

        // Validate pagination input from URL
        $this->validate($request, [
            'sort_by' => 'alpha_dash',
            'direction' => 'alpha_dash',
            'page_size' => 'integer'
        ]);
        // Keeps page size less than a 1000 records being pulled
        if ($page_size > 1000) $page_size = 1000;

        $records = Product::with('manufacturer')->with('source')->where('active', 1)->orderBy($sort_by, $direction)->paginate($page_size);
        $record_count = Product::where('active', 1)->count();

        return view('pages.products.index', compact('records','sort_by','direction','page_size','record_count'));
     }
```

Comment: What is the part of the code that is repeated in every function?

Comment: the portion of the code that needs to be in every *extended Controller* goes in the `Controller` class itself so that it is available for all extended Controllers.

Comment: It doesn't seems to me that you require to make any code common...?? Can you tell which code you can make common for all?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you need pagination in **every** controller so I would probably create a new class called `PagedController` that extends `Controller` and put the functionality in there. If you do need it in every controller then i would go with what @WEBjuju said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper:

```
class Helper {
    public static function handlePagination($request, $validate, $rules = []) {
        // Pagination. Grab sort_by, direction and page size.  If empty assign defaults
        $sort_by = (empty($request->input('sort_by'))) ? 'id' : $request->input('sort_by');
        $direction = (empty($request->input('direction'))) ? 'asc' : $request->input('direction');
        $page_size = (empty($request->input('page_size'))) ? '10' : $request->input('page_size');

        // Validate pagination input from URL
        $validate($request, [
            'sort_by' => 'alpha_dash',
            'direction' => 'alpha_dash',
            'page_size' => 'integer'
        ]); // @TODO: append $rules to ruleset

        // Keeps page size less than a 1000 records being pulled
        if ($page_size > 1000) {
            $page_size = 1000;
        }

        return compact('sort_by', 'direction', 'page_size');
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
class ProductController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        list($sort_by, $direction, $page_size) = Helper.handlePagination($request, $this->validate);

        $records = Product::with('manufacturer')
            ->with('source')
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->orderBy($sort_by, $direction)
            ->paginate($page_size);
        $record_count = Product::where('active', 1)->count();

        return view('pages.products.index', compact('records','sort_by','direction','page_size','record_count'));
     }
}
```

Comment: I used your code with a little modification and it worked perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could create a base controller which contains the duplicated code and extend that base controller in your others.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class myController extends Controller {

    public function paginate(Request $request){

        // Pagination. Grab sort_by, direction and page size.  If empty assign defaults
        $sort_by = (empty($request->input('sort_by'))) ? 'id' : $request->input('sort_by');
        $direction = (empty($request->input('direction'))) ? 'asc' : $request->input('direction');
        $page_size = (empty($request->input('page_size'))) ? '10' : $request->input('page_size');

         // Validate pagination input from URL
        $this->validate($request, [
            'sort_by' => 'alpha_dash',
            'direction' => 'alpha_dash',
            'page_size' => 'integer'
        ]);
        // Keeps page size less than a 1000 records being pulled
        if ($page_size > 1000) $page_size = 1000;
            $records = Product::with('manufacturer')->with('source')->where('active', 1)->orderBy($sort_by, $direction)->paginate($page_size);
            $record_count = Product::where('active', 1)->count();
            return view('pages.products.index', compact('records','sort_by','direction','page_size','record_count'));
        }
    }
}
```

**Your Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ProductController extends myController {
    public function index(Request $request){
        $this->paginate();
    }
}
```